# laravel payload too large in production

Tags: laravel

I am getting error 413 in my production server laravel. It is saying "payload too large". The code is working in xampp. my website is in a subdomain of a domain. How do I correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

Set `client_max_body_size` will sort this issue

If **Ngnix**

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    ...
}
```

If **Apache** (in `.htaccess`)

```
 LimitRequestBody 104857600
```

> **In addition [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)**